# Dockerfile issue: cannot copy folder from source(host) to destination(container) folder

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

As a workaround for not being able to properly handle local dependencies via npm link, I am trying to have Dockerfile copy the symlinked folders to the node_modules folder after I run npm install like so:

```
FROM node:latest

ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /usr/src/app && cp -a /tmp/package-lock.json /usr/src/app && cp -a /tmp/package.json /usr/src/app

COPY node_modules/modlib1 /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb-repository
COPY node_modules/modlib2 /usr/src/app/node_modules/redis-repository
```

Every time the `Dockerfile` executes to the copy line, I receive the following error:

> ERROR: Service 'container1' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder831774561/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/modlib1: no such file or directory

Here is a sample of my docker-compose.yml section for this service:

```
container_name: "modlib"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - rabbitmq
```

I have tried COPY, ADD, etc.  I even commented out the sections pertaining to node_modules in my .dockerignore file.

What could possibly be blocking these copy operations?  I just want to copy the local dependencies over to the node_modules folder.

Comment: Where is the node_modules folder? Is it inside your build context included at the end of your `docker build` command?

Comment: Yes.  It is in the same folder as the project, Dockerfile and node_modules.

Comment: Hi user1790300. A minor aside: I've edited some of your questions to remove chatty material, including whether you appreciate help (it's assumed) and how long you've been stuck (it's irrelevant). Would you refrain from this sort of material in future postings please?

Comment: "no such file or directory" is pretty explicit! You say it is in the same folder - is it perhaps a soft link?

Comment: @SiKing I used npm link command to create it.

Comment: I do not use npm, but that sounds like a "yes". Docker cannot see links! You have to make it a real file, or at least a hard link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy):

> The  path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot COPY ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.

In other words, only files in the current directory and below will be sent to the "context". Anything outside of the current directory, including simlinks, will be ignored!

Comment: With that said, what is the fix for this scenario?  I have local dependencies that are npm linked to avoid having to do fresh installs everytime I make changed to the modules.

Comment: @user1790300 You will have to create a hard-link, if npm supports that. Or a staging area where you prepare all the files that Docker needs to consume.